# how to execute ".sh" file from wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, shell, wordpress, exec

I am writing a plugin for my client to run a sync for their products on that website.
This sync file is basically a .sh file to take backup for existing database.
In this wordpress plugin I have created simple button which submits the form which looks like below.

```
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST['cmdsync']))
       {
         echo exec("/home/trgt/webs/www.mywebsite.co.uk/zenlo_scripts/sync_vend_to_shopp.sh");
       }
       ?>
       <h2>Start syncing products from VEND to Shopp:</h2>
       <form action='#' method='post'>
           <input id="cmdsync" name="cmdsync" value="SYNC" type="submit" />
       </form>
```

The problem I am facing is the exec function is not doing anything not even creating a backup or echoing the return value. 
Can anyone help me how can i execute .sh script file from wordpress backend plugin interface?

The .sh looks like

!/

```
opt/local/bin/bash

DATE=`date`
cd /home/trgt/webs/www.mywebsite.co.uk/zenlo_scripts
/opt/local/bin/find db_backups -mtime +100 -name "trgt*.sql.gz" -delete
mysqldump -utrgt -p'password' DB_NAME | gzip -9 > "db_backups/trgt_tr_shopp_wp.backup.$DATE.sql.gz"
```

Comment: Does your host allow you to execute bash scripts?

Comment: Give a try to `shell_exec()` command

Comment: Does your bash file have the proper declaration at the top? try adding `/usr/bin/bash` or `bash` at the front of your exec statement? you can also add 2 arguments, `, $ret, $output` and you can evaluate the response from these

Comment: What is the file permission?

Comment: this is the script i want to run

Comment: !/opt/local/bin/bash

DATE=`date`
cd /home/trgt/webs/www.mywebsite.co.uk/zenlo_scripts
/opt/local/bin/find db_backups -mtime +100 -name "trgt*.sql.gz" -delete
mysqldump -utrgt -p'password' dbname | gzip -9 > "db_backups/trgt_tr_shopp_wp.backup.$DATE.sql.gz"

Comment: Please give a try to `exec("sh /home/trgt/webs/www.mywebsite.co.uk/zenlo_scripts/sync_vend_to_shopp.sh");`

Comment: No its not working @Zameer and the file permission is         -rwxrwxr--   1 trgt   other  sync_vend_to_shopp.sh

Comment: Please make it `rwxrwxrwx` and then try again

Comment: i have put this line at the end of .sh file and it shows current date time but it's now creating database backup @ZameerKhan             echo $DATE."ok2"

Comment: I am sorry i didn't get you. Is your problem sort?